# Conditionally continuing with Python unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a test rig with three sets of tests for a sudoku solver:

1. Test most functions individually
2. Test the final few functions, which use those in step 1
3. Test the final few functions with 95 harder puzzles

As step 3 takes a while, I'm looking for a way to only go to the next step if all the previous steps passed. Is it possible to do this using the unit test framework, or is it easier to write my own control structure?

Comment: I can tell you for sure, that this is possible in `doctest` tests, if you would like to know.

Comment: Done. A little research revealed some useful features of `unittest` you may be looking for. You did not mention the module you use for unit testing, so I assumed `unittest`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your tests structured in `unittest` test suites, you can execute the long-running test suite only if the first test suite passed without errors using the following piece of code:

```
suite1 = unittest.TestSuite()
suite2 = unittest.TestSuite()
# fill suites with test cases ...
result1 = unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite1)
if result1.wasSuccessful():
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite2)
```

Answer (score 8):

## Using `doctest`

If you wish to use **`doctest`**, then treat it just as Python IDLE (see [`doctest` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html) for tips on how to prepare tests), **assign results of the previous tests to some variables** and then **use conditional checks** for determining whether you wish to execute other tests. Just like that.

Unfortunately it has nothing to do with [`unittest`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html).

## Using `unittest`

### Command-line options for `unittest`

When it comes to `unittest`, you can still invoke it from command line using [`-f` (`--failfast`) option](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#cmdoption-unittest-f), so it **stops test run on the first error or failure**.

### Skipping tests

`unittest` supports skipping tests based on some conditions ([see documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures)) or when you know the test is broken and you do not want to count it as failure. See basic skipping example:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @unittest.skip("demonstrating skipping")
    def test_nothing(self):
        self.fail("shouldn't happen")

    @unittest.skipIf(mylib.__version__ < (1, 3),
                     "not supported in this library version")
    def test_format(self):
        # Tests that work for only a certain version of the library.
        pass

    @unittest.skipUnless(sys.platform.startswith("win"), "requires Windows")
    def test_windows_support(self):
        # windows specific testing code
        pass
```

Was it helpful?